# how to disable the "CSRF protection " in jenkins by default

Tags: debian, jenkins

I need to disable the CSRF protection in jenkins, which is enabled by default.
The problem is after containerizing this, when ever i spun up a new container with jenkins inside it, it throws a "No valid crumb " error.

i am currenty using this cmd to turn on the jenkins application.

```
/usr/bin/java  -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration=false  -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=9090 --ajp13Port=-1
```

Comment: "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure Global Security": is "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" selected? If it is, deselect it.

Comment: I need a cli based cmd to disable that,, as the Jenkins is running behind kube proxy it keeps on crashing during the initial installation...

Comment: fwiw, the option "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure Global Security": is "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" doesn't exist/is missing on our Jenkins 2.233 instance.

Answer (score 14):

To disable CSRF, it can be done with groovy, open "Manage Jenkins" / "Script Console"

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def instance = Jenkins.instance
instance.setCrumbIssuer(null)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57869141

Comment: How to do this permanently? The above changes are going off after restarting the Jenkins.

Comment: You can create a Groovy script file $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy, or any .groovy file in the directory $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/, to run some additional things right after Jenkins starts up.

Answer (score 1):

I just add

```
-Dhudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION=true
```

So the full command is:

```
docker run  --restart=always --name jenkins --add-host="xxxx:xx" --add-host="updates.jenkins-ci.org:7.223.199.227" --add-host="updates.jenkins.org:7.223.199.227"  -u root  -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000  -v /root/jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   -e JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai -Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true -Dhudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION=true"  docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @hoefling, after the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery" parameter is deselected. Save it.

Goto Manage Jenkins and click on Reload Configuration from Disk.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about your use case, but you always have the option of creating a new Docker image using a `Dockerfile` and running that image instead. In the `Dockerfile`, you'd set your system properties using the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration=false
```